# Creating an XSLT Template based on XSD File (all nodes) and a dynamic client XML (with only 50 % nodes and values)

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xsd

In application client generates an XML and then convert it to PDF. (using FONET)

PDF has a fixed format and its displays all the possible nodes (whether data or not) in tabular format.

Each parent node in XML is a section in PDF which has a complex UI structure. In total PDF has 34 sections.

XML is dynamic and will always have 18-20 sections only. And with in each section (parent node) child nodes with no values will be missing.

Only way to know the 100 % XML structure is from an XSD file.

**Question:**

IS there any way to use both XML and XSD in XSLT to generate a PDF or we need something intermediate?

May be a fixed XML with all the possible nodes and then add client generated XML values to it?

Comment: The XSD schema language is rather complex, processing XSD with all its complexity is a difficult task. I think Saxonica has an schema export tool http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!schema-processing/scm to alleviate that task. But I don't think your few sentences really describe which problems you have run into.

Comment: There are tools to generate an XML instance from XSD. The result can be used for writing an XSLT that handles all nodes that can possibly appear in the input. This is much easier then writing against an XSD. Note that this is assuming each node needs to be always handled the same way, regardless of the presence of other nodes.

Comment: How are different elements going to be processed? The same, or differently? What information in the schema are you going to use in order to decide how to process a particular element?

Comment: Thanks, I generated a Sample XML and will use it to create a template targetting all the nodes and sub Nodes. The only pending is, lot of XML Node use "Codes: instead of Actual text which is present in the documentation for that particular element eg <Status>Res<Status>  and <xs:element name="ResidentialStatus">
     <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
       RES - Resident
       NRI - Non Resident
       NOR - Resident but not Ordinarily resident
      </xs:documentation>
     </xs:annotation>

Answer (score 0):

Regarding PDF generation from XSL, you can use xsl:fo to generate PDF.

For dynamic XML, i would say just write a generic template as an example if you have multiple sections on different level then just write a single template .

Also if you need to capture all the elements for which you have not written any template match then just write an identity template to copy all these elements in output:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I hope this will help you, if you need more details then please share input and output sample.

Comment: Thanks, We are using FONET for PDF generation.